# XSLT CallTemplate ForEach XML extension function

Tags: java, templates, xslt

I want the $content to be the expected string. I know that copy-of instead of value-of $content produces the expected string. But how do I not use copy-of and pass it to say a java extension function?

I asked a different related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096832/xslt-calltemplate-foreach-xml).

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
  <b c="d"/>
  <b c="d"/>
  <b c="d"/>
</a>
```

### XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="foo">
        <xsl:param name="content"></xsl:param>
        <!-- <xsl:copy-of select="$content"></xsl:copy-of> -->
        <!-- copy-of produces the expected string here, but how to pass to Java -->
        <xsl:value-of select="java:someMethod($content)" />
        <!-- I want the content to be the expected string -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="foo">
            <xsl:with-param name="content">
                <xsl:for-each select="a/b">
                    <e>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@c" />
                    </e>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired String to be passed to Java extension function from $content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<e>d</e>
<e>d</e>
<e>d</e>
```

PS: Calling foo is mandatory.

Ultimately, my objective is to emulate result-document in XSLT 1.0 with extension function.

Comment: Well which kind of parameter does your method `someMethod` expect? Which XSLT (2.0?) processor exactly do you use? In XSLT 1.0 terms you are passing in a result tree fragment, in XSLT 2.0 a temporary tree fragment to the extension function. How that translates into a Java class depends on the XSLT processor used. It will not be a string however, rather an instance of a class representing result tree fragments respectively tree fragments in the implementation of the used XSLT processor.

Comment: someMethod expects a String. I am using XSLT 1.0 (sorry about the stylesheet attr.) I am using Java's [TransformerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html). What I want to do is do something similar to result-document in XSLT 1.0 with an extension function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Java extension functions depends on which XSLT processor you are using, which you haven't told us. If you use Java's TransformerFactory you will get whatever is on the classpath, for example the built-in version of Xalan, the Apache version of Xalan, or Saxon.

Your description suggests you want to pass a string containing lexical XML to your Java extension function. That implies you need to serialize a node to a string. That can't be achieved without an extension function such as saxon:serialize(). It's probably easier to pass the node to your Java method, and have the Java method do the serialization.

Comment: Built-in Apache Xalan is my processor. Hmmm..., basically in my situation the xslt for processing nodes is written by someone else and the extension templates are written as library and imported, so I will expose a serialize function to that developer. Thanks, I will wait a bit before marking as answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually Xalan from Apache is not the same processor as the version of Xalan built into the JDK. There are not many differences, except that the Apache version has fewer bugs.